# XML Layout - Entry Identifier 0x11a is larger than entry count 0xb2

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

'Entry Identifier 0x11a is larger than entry count 0xb2'

This is what's printed in my LogCat when switching to a specific fragment.

I think it may have something to do with my 'xml layout' resource being inflated. I am not sure what though.

**My Question**

Has anybody else had this problem or know what it means?

Thanks for your help

Comment: From some looking around, it looks like something to do with styles being missing or incorrectly ordered. Check that any styles you reference are in your resource folder or that you are referencing themes available on your Android version.

Comment: can we see some code on the switching?

Comment: Please add some code and layouts to your question

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered this problem and worked around it with a hack. I added an empty style at the top of my styles.xml:

```
<style name="empty_style" />
```

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/6UZQoOBtPtk) discussion on Google Groups the error occurs

> ...when HistoryRecord over in the framework is trying to read the theme defined in your resources. There isn't anything wrong with the code [...].  In fact, if you fiddle around with the ordering in your styles.xml, usually adding a few empty  blocks near the top, might help get around this 
>   temporarily.

I can't say if the cause quoted above is real, but it removed the issue for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Gunnar.Unfortunately this didn't solve the problem for me :(

Comment: Just ran into this problem 6 years later and that link fixed it.  Thanks!